# Calculate difference of two value with same ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanna calculate difference between two value like in this picture.

[image]

We have a random interval between each "False" and Packet can timeout.

So, we can have a idPaquet and TimeSend but no TimeReceive

Any clues, please?

Comment: What is the expected output based on your example? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula depends on your data. If the cells with `FAUX` are not formatted as text, then

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$10)*($A$2:$A$10=E2))-SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$10)*($A$2:$A$10=E2))
```

would be sufficient. In exchange for `SUMPRODUCT`, you could also use `SUMIF`.

If the other cells are not properly formatted, you would need to use this **ARRAY-FORMULA:  CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER($C$2:$C$10),($C$2:$C$10))*($A$2:$A$10=E2))-SUMPRODUCT((IF(ISNUMBER($B$2:$B$10),$B$2:$B$10)*($A$2:$A$10=E2))).
```

which checks for for numbers.

[image]